# SharePoint 2016 PWA site not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, project-server, pwa

I have installed SharePoint 2016 Server on Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2014. I have created a content database and enabled SP features using below cmd.

```
Enable-SPFeature pwasite -URL $http://XYZ/sites/pwa
```

I received success message but when I trying to access URL using Site Primary Administrator account, then system redirected me to an error page saying:

> "Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred."

I am stuck with this issue for a couple of days and not able to setup project server 2016.

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the log/event viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the PWA Instance is not configured properly, you should first enable `Project Server License` using the below cmdlet

```
 Enable-ProjectServerLicense -Key xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```

> **Note:** Although Project Server 2016 is included as part of the SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise installation, it still requires a
>   separate license. (**Trial key**:`Y2WC2-K7NFX-KWCVC-T4Q8P-4RG9W`)

---

**To configure Project Server 2016, you should do the following:**

- Enable Project Server 2016 License.
- Creating a Project Server 2016 service application.
- Deploy Project Web App.

  - Create a Web Application.
  - Create a PWA Content Database.
  - Lock Down PWA Content Database to prevent any new site collections being added except  PWA site.
- Finally, use Powershell to Create PWA Site and Enable PWA Site Feature

  ```
  #Create a PWA site collection
  New-SPSite -ContentDatabase PWA_Content -URL http://epm/sites/PWA -Template pwa#0
  #enable PWA Site Feature
  Enable-SPFeature pwasite -URL http://epm/sites/PWA
  ```

Please check the details steps at

- [Install and Configure Project Server 2016.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/install-and-configure-project-server-2016/)
- [Project Server 2016 Configuration.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37674.project-server-2016-configuration.aspx)

Or use the below script to auto-configure Project Server 2016

- [Project Server 2016 Configurator Script (Auto-Installer)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Script-to-9993a79d)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68230/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-sharepoint-2016-pwa-site-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

After several days of R&D, I came to know that The server farm account is also used by below:

```
Web Application Pool - SharePoint - 80
```

Which leads to fail SPTimerService (SPTimerV4).

Thanks M.Qassas for your support so far.